# Vue.js with Ionic 5: not working directives

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionic-framework

So i have basically a problem that Vue.js directives such as `v-model` does not work with ionic 5. I follow guides on youtube using Ionic 4 and it just doesn't work for me for Ionic 5.
For example to make the `v-model` work i needed to write this code:

```
<ion-input :value="name"
                @ionInput="name = $event.target.value;"
                @ionClear="searchCleared($event)" type="text" 
                placeholder="Enter name"></ion-input>
         <ion-label>{{name}}</ion-label>
```

(I've added the `ion-label` so i can see if the value is changing while i input letters).
And in the script:

```
<script>
import { IonContent, IonPage} from '@ionic/vue';
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';
import {alertController} from '@ionic/vue';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Home',
  components: {
    IonContent,
    IonPage
  },

  data(){
    return{
      name: ""
    }
  },

  methods: {
..........
```

if I write it like this:

```
<ion-input v-model="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter name"></ion-input>
<ion-label>{{name}}</ion-label>
```

it does not work as intended

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>An Input Field</ion-label>
  <ion-input v-model="inputField" type="text"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

you can just use `v-model` with latest version of ionic

Comment: v-model doesn't work for me. As i mentioned above, i write that code to make v-model work.   
Specifically: 
<ion-input :value="name"
                        @ionInput="name = $event.target.value;"
                        @ionClear="searchCleared($event)" type="text" placeholder="Enter data to fetch (name)"></ion-input>

Comment: if it doesn't work then you are doing something else wrong.. i suggest you post more of your code

Comment: <ion-input :value="name"
                        @ionInput="name = $event.target.value;"
                        @ionClear="searchCleared($event)" type="text" placeholder="Enter name of Pokemon"></ion-input>

And in the script:  data(){
    return{
      name: ""
    }
  } .......
If i try to just put v-model to connect those it won't work though

Comment: I added the code on the original post, check it out if you will

Comment: you didn't follow the directions I provided, post what you have tried based on the answer I gave you because I know the solution works, you just posting the wrong code again isn't helpful... post your code with the v-model as I suggested and show me how that is not working

Comment: I told you, if i try the solution you provided the value of 'name' does not change while i input letters in the input field.

Comment: you haven't imported IonItem, IonLabel or IonInput

Comment: Indeed, thank you very much.